# make daemon script for "cat /proc/stat > /some/file"

Tags: debian, daemon

I need daemon script which every 3 seconds call command: cat /proc/stat > /some/file

can anybody help me how make and setup this? (system is debian squeeze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
   cat /proc/stat > /some/file
   sleep 3
done
```

and run it with `/path/to/scrip.sh &`

(use the trailing `&` to run it in the background, that is: "daemon" mode)

it's not very sophisticated (e.g. the only awy to stop it once it's started is by killing it), but does what you asked for.